# Mono "Hello World" example working, but Java is not

Tags: maven, testing, selenium, maven-surefire-plugin, saucelabs

I'm running the [Getting Started Examples](https://saucelabs.com/home) from the Sauce Labs homepage both with Java and C# Mono.

The Mono example works like a charm, but the Java one reports that

`Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.`

I've tried re-writing the Java example to be similar to the Mono example as such:

```
public class WebDriverTest {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("version", "10");
        capabilities.setCapability("platform", Platform.LINUX);
        capabilities.setCapability("name", "Testing Selenium 2 with C# on Sauce");
        capabilities.setCapability("username", "banksysan");
        capabilities.setCapability("accessKey", "MY-APP-KEY");

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                new URL("http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }

    @Test
    public void webDriver() throws Exception {
        driver.get("http://www.amazon.com/");
        assertEquals("Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs & more", driver.getTitle());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Any other suggestions?

Thanks

**Update**

I've tried running as described in the [tutorial](https://saucelabs.com/java) as suggested by Ross below, following this verbatum causes Maven to exit with the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project sauce-labs-tutorial: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ? -> [Help 1]
```

I have edited the sauce files, just adding the `package` declaration which is missing, however adding this didn't make any difference at all.

**UPDATE 2**

Complete Maven stack trace:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Forking command line: /bin/sh -c cd /home/david/Documents/development/sauceLabs/java/sauce-labs-tutorial && /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_11/jre/bin/java -jar /home/david/Documents/development/sauceLabs/java/sauce-labs-tutorial/target/surefire/surefirebooter5443687714708881867.jar /home/david/Documents/development/sauceLabs/java/sauce-labs-tutorial/target/surefire/surefire4108475136019888668tmp /home/david/Documents/development/sauceLabs/java/sauce-labs-tutorial/target/surefire/surefire_08561306448128018862tmp
Running TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3:16.389s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 13 20:17:58 GMT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/213M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14:test (default-test) on project sauce-labs-tutorial: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] at dave.WebDriverWithHelperTest.getSessionId(WebDriverWithHelperTest.java:78)
[ERROR] at com.saucelabs.testng.SauceOnDemandTestListener.markJobAsFailed(SauceOnDemandTestListener.java:103)
[ERROR] at com.saucelabs.testng.SauceOnDemandTestListener.onTestFailure(SauceOnDemandTestListener.java:97)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1895)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1879)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1292)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:77)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:189)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:105)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:117)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:158)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14:test (default-test) on project sauce-labs-tutorial: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dave.WebDriverWithHelperTest.getSessionId(WebDriverWithHelperTest.java:78)
    at com.saucelabs.testng.SauceOnDemandTestListener.markJobAsFailed(SauceOnDemandTestListener.java:103)
    at com.saucelabs.testng.SauceOnDemandTestListener.onTestFailure(SauceOnDemandTestListener.java:97)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1895)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1879)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1292)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dave.WebDriverWithHelperTest.getSessionId(WebDriverWithHelperTest.java:78)
    at com.saucelabs.testng.SauceOnDemandTestListener.markJobAsFailed(SauceOnDemandTestListener.java:103)
    at com.saucelabs.testng.SauceOnDemandTestListener.onTestFailure(SauceOnDemandTestListener.java:97)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1895)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1879)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1292)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There was an error in the forked process
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dave.WebDriverWithHelperTest.getSessionId(WebDriverWithHelperTest.java:78)
    at com.saucelabs.testng.SauceOnDemandTestListener.markJobAsFailed(SauceOnDemandTestListener.java:103)
    at com.saucelabs.testng.SauceOnDemandTestListener.onTestFailure(SauceOnDemandTestListener.java:97)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1895)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1879)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1292)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:475)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:349)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:806)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:701)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:629)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Browsong the WWW it looks like surefire has been spotted as a possible culprit.  I've upgraded the version in the POM but the problem still persists.

Comment: Do you have the selenium grid and node running? and is the node properly registering to the hub?

Comment: @alexxp03 I do not have the grid running...  It isn't mentioned at all in the Hell World app on their home page.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I misunderstood what the setup was like.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try create the RemoteWebDriver instance using the following code:

```
 driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
            new URL("http://banksysan:MY-APP-KEY@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

We've also created a [more in-depth tutorial](http://saucelabs.com/java) on getting Java tests to work with Sauce Labs, which might help too.

---

Update: The underlying error that was generated was

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d185a80fa4206dfeab80ba773c04ac33c0', time: '2013-02-27 13:51:26'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.5.0-25-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_11'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

which in turn was due to a proxy server that was blocking the outbound request to ondemand.saucelabs.com.

Including the proxy information by specifying Java system properties resolved the issue, eg.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);            
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort)            
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", userName);            
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", password);
```

Comment: Hi Ross, I originally tries that method of opening the RemoteWebDriver.  In fact, that's the way given in the example but it still wouldn't connect.  I'll look through the detailed tutorial today.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ross, I just tried what you suggested, Maven exits with this error `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project sauce-labs-tutorial: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ? -> [Help 1]`.  I've updated the question, but do you have any more suggestions?  Cheers.

Comment: Hi, it looks like the error is because the driver instance is null, and the code isn't handling the null driver (the class with the error is WebDriverWithHelperTest, which demonstrates how to use the Sauce TestNG helper libraries to invoke the Sauce REST API as part of the test).  Are there any testng output files with additional stack traces that indicate *why* the driver might be null?

Comment: I've run this with just the `WebDriverTest` class and get the same result.  Stepping through code, it does indeed fail to create the `RemoteWebDriver`, but I can't see the line as it's replaces with`/* compiled code */`.  I've emailed the full surefire details to your office, but they don't say anything new.

Comment: The process hangs for a couple of minutes before failing... Not sure if that info helps at all.