# Strange version number in SauceLabs Java archetype

Tags: java, maven, selenium, pom.xml, saucelabs

I'm trying to get the Java 'getting started' app to work and I noticed this in the POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>sauce_testng</artifactId>
    <version>[1.0.0,)</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**<version>[1.0.0,)</version>**

Is this right?  Could it be accounting for the problems I'm having in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366563) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is fine as per [Version Range Specification](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html) of maven.

`[1.0.0,)` means a version `x` where `x >= 1.0.0`

> Default strategy: Of the overlapping ranges, the highest soft
>   requirement is the version to be used. If there are no soft
>   requirements inside the prescribed ranges, the most recent version is
>   used. If that does not fit the described ranges, then the most recent
>   version number in the prescribed ranges is used. If the ranges exclude
>   all versions, an error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, as per Nishant's answer, we included the version range so that when new versions of the sauce_testng library are released, they are included automatically when a new build is run.